# Radio buttons layout to make horizontal

Tags: aem

I am designing a dialog in which i want the radio buttons displayed horizontally and not vertically, so that appear in a single line. Any ideas how to achieve this.

Below is my dialog.xml.

```
<items
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        xtype="tabpanel">
        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <tab1
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Panel"
                title="Slider">
                <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                    <typeconfigs
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        fieldLabel="Select Videos"
                        name="./options"
                        xtype="customconfigmultifield">
                        <fieldConfigs jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                            <gridlayout
                                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                itemId="dispotions"
                                name="selcttab"
                                type="radio"
                                xtype="selection">
                                <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                    <grid1
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        text="grid1"
                                        value="grid1"/>
                                    <grid2
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        text="grid2"
                                        value="grid2"/>
                                    <grid3
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        text="grid3"
                                        value="grid3"/>
                                    <grid4
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        text="grid4"
                                        value="grid4"/>
                                </options>
                            </gridlayout>
                        </fieldConfigs>
                        <limit
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            maxVal="{Long}6"/>
                    </typeconfigs>
                </items>
            </tab1>
        </items>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [ExtJS Layouts](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html) for the same. There are various ways of configuring the same, one of which could be using an **hbox** layout as shown below.

Use the `layout` config available for [Selection Widget](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.Selection) and set its value to `hbox`. Then use the `optionsConfig` to set the width that applies to each radio box. Since the optionsConfig accepts an object, create it is a child node of your selection and then set the required styles.

Sample Dialog Structure shown below.

```
<gridlayout
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    itemId="dispotions"
    name="selcttab"
    type="radio"
    xtype="selection"
    layout="hbox">
    <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <grid1
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            text="grid1"
            value="grid1"/>
        <grid2
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            text="grid2"
            value="grid2"/>
        <grid3
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            text="grid3"
            value="grid3"/>
        <grid4
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            text="grid4"
            value="grid4"/>
    </options>
    <optionsConfig 
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        width="60" />
</gridlayout>
```

This solution works in general, however, i notice that there is a custom widget `customconfigmultifield` defined under which you are configuring a selection field. So you might need to tweak your styles accordingly.